# How to get server response with MutableLiveData in background thread?

Tags: java, android, mutablelivedata

I have to take a picture with inside android application. For that purpose I'm using this callback:

```
CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
                    = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    uploadImageToServer()
}
```

```
private void uploadImageToServer() {
     viewModel.postData(data).observe(
                getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<ApiResponse<ResponseBody>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ApiResponse<ResponseBody> response) {
                viewModel.isLoading().postValue(false);
            }
        });
}
```

But I'm getting the error of not being able to call `observe` method from background thread: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke observe on a background thread`

Does any solution for this exists? Thanks.

Comment: It seems that you are observing only to change the isLoading state, so observe directly this liveData in the onViewCreated and to upload the image, pass the data to your viewmodel. This ViewModel upload the loading when you invoke it and when is finished, upload it to false state... you must have another liveData or another mechanism to handle the error.

Comment: You mean to put observe method in onViewCreated and to call only `viewModel.postData(data);` inside `uploadImageToServer()` method? How to know when upload is finished to use response from server? Does that get set as a MutableLiveData field variable inside ViewModel instance?

Comment: the it will necessary to change the aprroach... the ui only must be show data, no receives the server response... create three livedata: loading, error, data... and the viewmodel knows if the call has an error, for example, receiving an exception using try catch...